# How to directly access and play a video from Photos Library?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to play a video that I saved to a user's Photo Library using ReplayKit. The name of the file is `myVideo.mp4` and the URL is `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/85309C83-6627-4582-9598-8125AB8A2929/Documents/myVideo.mp4`

I'm trying to access this video but my research has lead me to

1.Picking the video (myVideo.mp4)

`imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]`

2.Retrieving the URL

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
            let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
        }
```

3.Using the retrieved URL in conjunction with AVPlayer to play the video.

Ideally I want to avoid these steps because I assume either the file name or URL that I have is sufficient enough to directly access my video.

Comment: This will help you [Pick video and play using AVPlayer](https://theswiftdev.com/picking-and-playing-videos-in-swift/)

Comment: Hey @TusharMoradiya, thanks for the article. Unfortunately they're using the same approach by getting the URL when they picked the video.